# Word.ParagraphFormat properties working incorrectly

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

I've got a bit of an issue where the Word.ParagraphFormat properties are not working. Here is my code:

```
private void ThisDocument_Startup(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Word.ParagraphFormat format = new Word.ParagraphFormat();

    format.Alignment = Word.WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphLeft; 
    // text is as if it were center alignment; behaves like ".wdAlighnParagraphCenter"

    format.OutlineLevel = Word.WdOutlineLevel.wdOutlineLevelBodyText; 
    // text boundaries around every section after line return rather than the entire page text and header/footer; behaves like ".wdOutlineLevelX" (X for 1-9)

    Word.Style stl = Styles[Word.WdBuiltinStyle.wdStyleNormalTable] as Word.Style;
    stl.UnhideWhenUsed = true;
    stl.ParagraphFormat = paragraphFormat;
    stl.NoSpaceBetweenParagraphsOfSameStyle = true;
}
```

Is there something I need to add or take away? Is there something else that needs to be set or assigned? Or, is there something over writing it later?

Comment: "Not working" is not a proper problem statement. What does it do and what did you expect it to do?

Comment: You need to assign the format to something, at the moment its just a disconnected object, e.g. doc.paragraphs[i].range = format;

Comment: @jwdonahue please see the comments within the code

Comment: @Alex K. I have updated the code

Comment: I agree with Alex K. The `ParagraphFormat` object doesn't work the way you think it should - this is old-style VBA, not modern .NET. You can't populate the object then assign it to something else (it would be nice!). You need to do stl.ParagraphFormat.Alignment =

Comment: Just to confirm, something like `stl.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = Word.WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphLeft;` and `stl.ParagraphFormat.OutlineLevel = Word.WdOutlineLevel.wdOutlineLevelBodyText;`?

Comment: If you want to get someone's attention you need to "ping" them by putting a "@" in front of their name: @UrbanCohort. Yes, that's how you need to do it. Create the style, then assign properties. I'll write it up in an Answer

Comment: @CindyMeister My apologizes, I was not aware of that. Thanks for getting back to me

Answer (score 0):

The Office object models work differently than the .NET object models - the technology is over twenty years old and the way people thought was different. In the Office object models you need to first create the object. Only then can you define its properties. (As opposed to that, in the .NET world you can define properties, then create the object and assign the properties.)

So for defining a Style you go about it more like this:

```
private void ThisDocument_Startup(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Word.Style Stl = Styles[Word.WdBuiltinStyle.wdStyleHeading1] as Word.Style;

    Stl.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = Word.WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphLeft; 

    Stl.ParagraphFormat.OutlineLevel = Word.WdOutlineLevel.wdOutlineLevelBodyText; 

    Stl.UnhideWhenUsed = true;
    Stl.NoSpaceBetweenParagraphsOfSameStyle = true;
}
```

Also please note that you can't set the above properties for a *Table* style, as in your question's sample code. These settings are only appropriate for paragraph (or linked - although I strongly advise against using linked) styles.

Comment: I think the assignment on second line within the method needs to be `Word.WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphLeft;`

Comment: @CindyMeister Hmm, I tried putting that code snippet in but I'm left with the same result. I'm beginning to wonder if something else in the code is interfering with the Word Styling. Any pointers on what else to look for or attempt?

Comment: @UrbanCohort It's not clear HOW the code isn't working for you. I've looked at the comments in the code, but they don't give me enough information. Could you [edit] your question with clear steps on how to reproduce what you're seeing? That's including how to set up a test document that the code runs on. My answer only addresses the question about how to correctly assign paragraph formatting to a style, not why a style may not be giving the result you expect.